# Conditions in JOINed tables shows error CakePHP

Tags: sql, cakephp, join, where-clause

I have two tables `employee_personals` where all the personal record of the employee is stored and `telephone_bills` where the telephone bills paid to a particular employee is stored for each month. Now in my `employeePersonalsController.php` I have a function called `api_show_employees()` which is similar to below :

```
function api_show_employees() {
      //$this->autoRender = false;
      //Configure::write("debug",0);

      $office_id = '';
      $cond = '';

      if(isset($_GET['office_id']) && trim($_GET['office_id']) != '') {
        $office_id = $_GET['office_id'];
        $cond['EmployeePersonal.office_id'] = $office_id;
      }


      if(isset($_GET['telephoneBillTo']) && isset($_GET['telephoneBillFrom']) ) {
        if($_GET['telephoneBillTo'] != '' && $_GET['telephoneBillFrom'] != '') {
          $cond['TelephoneBill.bill_from'] = $_GET['telephoneBillFrom'];
          $cond['TelephoneBill.bill_to'] = $_GET['telephoneBillTo'];
        }
      }


      $order = 'EmployeePersonal.name';
     // $employee = $this->EmployeePersonal->find('all');
      $employee = $this->EmployeePersonal->find('all',array('order' => $order,'conditions'=>$cond));
      //return json_encode($employee);
    }
```

This functions basically finds all the employees who paid bills in the given period. But I am getting an error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'TelephoneBill.bill_from' in 'where clause'
```

Models : `EmployeePersonal.php`:

```
var $hasMany = array(
  'TelephoneBill' => array(
         'className' => 'TelephoneBill',

     )
);
```

`TelephoneBill.php`

```
public $name = 'TelephoneBill';
var $hasMany = array('EmployeePersonal');
```

NB: If I skip the `bill_from` and `bill_to` conditions, I am getting the results , with `TelephoneBill` array !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** use [Joins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) instead.

---

**Details/Notes:**

1) it looks like you're using `recursive`.  Don't do that.  Use [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) instead.

2) You can't limit the parent model based on conditions against data from a contained/recursive-included table - **instead, use [Joins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)**.

2b) Or, you could query from the other direction, and query your `TelephoneBill` with conditions, then contain the `EmployeePersonal`.